# Split groups in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection `Rows` with fields `group1`, `group2`, and `group3` which are all numbers.

I can use the collection with

```
Template.tplName.helpers({
  rows: function() {
    return Rows.find({});
  },
});
```

and

```
<template name="tplName">
  {{#each rows}}
    {{group1}}, {{group2}}, {{group3}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

But instead of printing all rows on one page, I have to divide them in multiple pages.

On the first page I want to print a list of all unique `group1` values. If I click on a `group1` number, I am going to another page with a list of all unique `group2` values having the `group1` number which I have just click. When clicking on a `group2` number, I am going to a new page with a list of all unique `group3` values having both the `group1` number and `group2` number I have clicked.

If my dataset is

```
group1, group2, group3, amount
=======================
1, 1, 1, 200
1, 1, 2, 300
1, 2, 1, 250
1, 2, 2, 220
1, 2, 3, 200
2, 1, 1, 305
2, 1, 1, 290
```

I want the first page to list

```
<li><a href="?">1</a></li>
<li><a href="?">2</a></li>
```

If I'm on this first page click 1, I want the next second page to list

```
<li><a href="?">1</a></li>
<li><a href="?">2</a></li>
```

If I'm on this second page click 2, I want the next third page to list

```
<li><a href="?">1</a></li>
<li><a href="?">2</a></li>
<li><a href="?">3</a></li>
```

I hope it's understandable what I'm trying to do :-)

I guess I have to retrieve the entire collection and then filter them out.

```
var rows = Rows.find().fetch(); // fetch all rows
var group1Numbers = _.pluck(rows, "group1"); // get all group1 numbers
var group1NumbersUnique _.uniq(group1Numbers); // get all unique group1 numbers
```

giving me the unique `group1` numbers. Now I need some way to tell the router (or something else) that I have clicked one of the `group1` numbers and on the next route having `rows = Rows.find({group1: ?})` instead of showing all the rows.

But if I use `_.pluck()` I get the group numbers as a list - which is probably the easiest way to remove duplicates, but I also need the sums.

I think I can create a template

```
<template name="groupList">
  {{#each groups}}
    <p><a href="?">{{name}}</a> (amount: {{amount}})</p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

and a route

```
this.route('groupListFirst', {
  path: '/groups',
  template: 'groupList',
  waitOn: function() {
    return [
      subs.subscribe('groups'),
    ]
  },
  data: function() {
    var group1List = [
      {
        name: "1",
        amount: 200 + 300 + 250 + 220 + 200,
      },
      {
        name: "2",
        budget: 305 + 290,
      },
    ];

    return {
      groups: group1List,
    }
  },
});
```

and a new route being active after I have clicked one of the group1 links, showing all the group2 objects belonging to the clicked group1 link.
So if the user clicks on "1" among the group 1 links, it's probably something like

```
this.route('groupListSecond', {
  path: '/groups',
  template: 'groupList',
  waitOn: function() {
    return [
      subs.subscribe('groups'),
    ]
  },
  data: function() {
    var group2List = [
      {
        name: "1",
        amount: 200 + 300,
      },
      {
        name: "2",
        budget: 250 + 220 + 200,
      },
    ];

    return {
      groups: group2List,
    }
  },
});
```

and if the user further clicks 1 among the group2 links, it's

```
this.route('groupListThird', {
  path: '/groups',
  template: 'groupList',
  waitOn: function() {
    return [
      subs.subscribe('groups'),
    ]
  },
  data: function() {
    var group3List = [
      {
        name: "1",
        amount: 200,
      },
    ];

    return {
      groups: group3List,
    }
  },
});
```

These routes are created manually because I don't know how to do this automatically and register which link the user clicked, and only present the objects related to this group.

I guess this should be done from the collection, having multiple group numbers in each document, but if I cannot do it with this structure, I will have to split each group into separate collections.

Comment: I can't understand your data and how you break each record into pages (nothing, 1, 2) ??? What is the meaning of group1 to group3?

Comment: Instead of storing each group to each record when you at least want to divide them again, why do not store the values as three records (sets) for group1, group2, group3 like: { group:1, values: [1,2] }, { group: 2, values: [1,2] }, { group: 3, values: [1,2,3] }

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear. I have a collection with groups. But instead of listing all the groups, I have created some kind of a mapping. So I have added some fields to the group collection to indicate/imitate some levels.

Comment: You need to tell us what the groups mean. It looks like an accounting system & `group1` can mean either `amount` or `budget` which would fail entity integrity, meaning I'm 99% sure your ER model is wrong, but can't fix it with bogus names.

Comment: It's actually an accounting plan with "multiple levels". So the groups are nested. But I don't need to store any information on the different groups (except the last/deepest level), so I thought I could just have 1 level, and indicate the nested levels with additional fields, indicating the 'branch'.

Comment: Maybe it's more correct to actually create a group for each group, and use a `parentGroupId` field. It will perhaps also make it easier to store the sums

Comment: your question is very long and much of it describes a solution, but what is your actual question? It seems to be left implicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long question with lots of parts! So this will be a long answer with lots of parts. Bear with me:

## Part 1: Aggregating

No, Meteor does not (yet) support mongo-level aggregation. There are packages for this (on the server) but not the client-side mini-mongo. So you are correct that you need to pull all records and do this yourself (for now). However, you also mention you want to sum data (I presume as this is accounting-based from the comments), so `_.pluck()` isn't good enough. Maybe you could use a `_.groupBy()` and `_.reduce()` within a `_.map()` - perhaps like this:

```
var group1Totals = _.map(_.groupBy(rows, "group1"), function(documents, key) {
  return {groupId: key,
          total: _.reduce(documents, function(acc, doc) {
                   return acc += doc.amount;
                 }, 0)};
};
```

This should give you a new array of objects (called `group1Totals`) with `group1` and `total` properties. This is good enough to return as your template helper (Meteor will iterate through arrays as well as cursors within an `{{#each}}` block). You can reuse this code later on to only get the totals for group 2 but instead of starting with everything (`rows`), you can pass a filtered list into the `_.groupBy()` using `_.filter()` and grouping by "group2".

## Part 2: Routing

Iron Router does allow [parameters to be passed](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#route-parameters) as well as data contexts to be set. You need to define your route to include parameters and then set your links to pass these. Again, an example of your route might be:

```
Router.route('/group1/:groupId', {
  data: function() {
    var groupId = this.params.groupId;
    return Rows.find({group1: groupId});
  }
});
```

This will set the data context (`this`) of your template to the subset of the rows you have chosen. However, you also need to make sure that the links are calling the route with the right parameters. Iron Router also provides a built-in helper for this, `pathFor`, which you can use like this in your template (using the structure defined above):

```
<template name="groupList">
  {{#each groups}}
    <p>
      <a href="{{pathFor route='group1' groupId=groupId}}">
        {{name}}
      </a>
      (amount: {{total}})
    </p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

You should then repeat this (with appropriate tweaks) for each of your three groups. Remember group 2 will need to include **both** group 1 and group 2 in its `.find()` selection, so you'll probably need two route parameters.

## Endnotes

This is probably the easiest way given your current structure. I'm not sure if denormalisation is appropriate or desired for an accounting system. Or even using NoSQL for that matter! However, I'll assume you're using this for reporting, not recording. The solution here is a strict 3-group approach, other groups would need to be added manually. You could do things far more dynamically but your current data structure is not well-suited to that. You would probably need to look at hierarchical relationships and nodes versus leaf structures. Far beyond the scope of this question!

I think this is everything you need/have asked for.